# How to override a numpy method

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, oop

How can I override a numpy function as in the example below (setting a different default to the parameter dtype; and how can I find the parent class which belongs for example to numpy.array)?

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1.0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

np1 = np.array(a)
print(np1.dtype) # gives float64

# How do I override np.array to setting float16 and avoid the manual operation?
np1.dtype = 'float16'
print(np1.dtype)

# I think it could be something like this
class myarray(np.ndarray):
    def array(self):
        print('my array')
        super(myarray, self).array(dtype = 'float16')

np2 = np.array(a) # myarray is not working ..
print(np2)
print(np2.dtype)
```

Thanks & kind regards

Comment: Use  np.array(a, dtype='float16') when you need this type.

Comment: I know this argument. I only wanted to try this as a programming exercise.

Comment: Do you want this function to produce this `dtype` regardless of the inputs, or only when it would normally produced a `float64`?  Without the `1.0` in `a` it would have produced an `int` dtype.  For other inputs it produces a string dtype, or object.  `np.array` is a complex compiled function.  How it determines shape and dtype is a black-box to most us, that just works as expected (most of the time).  `np.ndarray` is the low-level constructor.  Look at `np.matrix` to see how you can construct a subclass with special attributes (in this case a fixed `ndim`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing `ndarray` is not trivial and `np.array` is not a method of that class anyway. Instead, it is simply a module-level function that returns a new array. You can wrap it in your own function:

```
def myarray(*args, **kwargs):
    """Create an array with forced dtype."""
    return np.array(*args, **kwargs, dtype='float16')

print(myarray([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # float16
```

If you want to change the behavior of `numpp.array` you can [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the function (**highly discouraged**):

```
def myarray(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['dtype'] = 'float16'  # override any dtype argument
    return np.core.multiarray.array(*args, **kwargs)  # use actual internal function to avoid infinite recursion

np.array = myarray  # apply monkey patch

print(np.array([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # float16
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `myarray` class when instantiating.

```
np2 = myarray.array(a) # myarray will work now
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not working. I get this error: `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.